# What pathway do I have to take to find Ending #1 in 999?

Tags: nine-hours-nine-persons-nine-doors

In Nine Hours Nine Persons Nine Doors, I've managed to find five of the six endings. The only one that remains is the ending indicated by the first of the six question mark boxes. I feel like I've exhausted every possible path, and yet still haven't found this ending!

Spoiling as little content of the path as possible, how do I find the first ending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first finish the ending where you open the safe *(which it sounds like you have)*.

Then go through doors `4`, `7`, and `1`, making all the right choices to let people blab at you.

The *"right"* choices are

> - Take the 4 leaf clover from santa
>  - Let June talk about the titanic (room 4) and Ice-9 experiment (in the freezer)
>  - Give it to clover in room 7 and talk to 7 about the Ice-9 experiment
>  - Say "Patch it up" to clover's question in door 7
>  - Yell at Ace to get out of room 1 when prompted
>  - Look at monitor after ZERO is spelled out on screen
>
>  [source](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/114/1142762p1.html)

Comment: Interesting, I'd taken that path before and had assumed that it would remain static regardless of what other endings I had found. Thanks!